# Regex to extract c/c++ from a webpage

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to web designing and I am currently designing a website for my college project. Right now, I am facing a problem which is as follows:

I am using perl to extract C/C++ codes from a link. I am using:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $link );
my $response = $ua->request($req);
my $results = $response->content;
```

to get the whole webpage in "result" variable. Then, I am removing JavaScript using:

```
while($results=~s/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>//gsi){};
```

Then finally to print the output I am using:

```
pos($results)=0;
$delim='{}';
while($results=~s/.*?($regex\s*?\(.*?\)\s*?)\{/\{/s)
{
  $code=$1 . extract_codeblock($results,$delim);
  print Dumper( "$code" . "\n" . "\n");
}
```

where my regex is:

```
my $regex='(((int|long|double|float|void)\s*?\w{1,25})|if|while|for)';
```

But this code is not giving the output. My regex is not correct. Can somebody suggest me a good regex to extract the cpp codes. By extracting codes the idea is to extract anything and everything in between "{" and "}" on the webpage.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If the code you are trying to extract is at some specific location in the page (e.g. in a `pre` tag with class `cpp`, then there are [easier ways](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) to extract that part than to use regexes. If the code is not designated by markup, this becomes extremely difficult: C++ can't be parsed with Perl regexes, and macros make it impossible to reliably distinguish code from ordinary text. Therefore: please post an example input of the page you are trying to process.

Comment: @roman28 can you provide the link of the page ?

Comment: @amon what i exactly want is to  extract any part of c/c++ code that i could find on the given link. Take a look at [**this**](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c19313/Creating-Your-Own-Search-Engine-for-CC-Code-Samples.htm). I want to implement this. The code given on their page is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For reading and parsing a webpage, I'd recommend that you use [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) and [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM).  Both come installed with [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious)

For a tutorial on using both of them, I'd recommend watching the 8 minute video at [`mojocast episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

Ideally, when working with the webpage, the type of content should be irrelevant.  Instead where it's placed on the page should be the only information you need to extract your desired data.